# Content Type x-www-form-urlencoded with URLs

Tags: quickbooks-online, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am writing a request to exchange an authorization code for a set of bearer tokens. This request requires the `x-www-form-urlencoded` `Conten Type`. The request body should include a `redirect_uri` property.

I'm hoping someone can explain why both versions of my `redirect_uri` are accepted by the resource server.

```
https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl

https%3A//developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

`%3A` is the url-encoded (percent-encoded) string `:`. So if you are looking at a string in a request body that is url-encoded, then `:` and `%3A` and `%3a` all represent the same character.

It's not necessary to encode it, but url-encoder functions typically don't make assumptions about does and does not have to be encoded in a given context, and just encode all special characters.